Как в Adobe Illustrator сделать так, чтобы при вращении манипулятора узла вращался только он один?
Как в Adobe Illustrator 23.1 при редактировании сетчатой заливки сделать так, чтобы при вращении манипулятора узла вращался только один, а не оба как на картинке ниже? Куда нажать?


Вам нужен не "Direct Selection", а "Anchor Point". Им же можно и заново пересоздать векторы, если потянуть от центральной точки.
